# Systemd won't respawn processes

Tags: linux, systemd

We have a forever running shell script handled by systemd which runs fine until some days ago, our server storage was 100% used because of some gigantic log files. I had to truncate those files in order to free some spaces.

Today, I got a report that the script is stopped running. But when I checked the status, it says :

```
● ImportantService.service - Important daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ImportantService.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-04-29 16:46:48 WIB; 5 days ago
  Process: 48877 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/importantScript stop --instance XYZ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 48889 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/importantScript start --instance XYZ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 48889 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 48.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/ImportantService.service
```

I noticed that it has 0 task, hence I restarted it manually. Now it runs normally. I suspected that the problem I mentioned earlier caused this.

The question is, how to make systemd respawn the processes if this kind of problem occur in the future?

---

Here's the .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description= Important daemon

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/importantScript start --instance XYZ
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/importantScript stop --instance XYZ

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**Update** : Some explanation regarding my script

The main functionality of `ImportantScript` is to enter a forever loop to do something if some event occurs in a given (arg) directory. And I should be able to launch multiple instances for different directories. Before I could start the script, I have to add a set of specifications of an instance, like :

```
ImportantScript add --name XYZ --dir /path/to/dir ..etc..
```

Now, I'm able to start instance of `XYZ`.

Every time I start an instance, it will store the PID to a file contains all predefined instances (using previous `add` command). PID that isn't listed means that corresponding instance is in idle state.

To stop an instance, I just have to call `ImportantScript stop --instance name`. It will terminate the process and delete the corresponding entry in the file, clean up its mess.

I hope this is not a systemd House of Horror entry.

Comment: rc scripts are only responsible for starting services and not maintaining it running. You should look forward onto something like `supervisor` daemon with proper config.

Comment: It's a good bet, given the `start` and `stop` verbs, that "importantScript" is _far from_ important and is more likely a Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisor and Bad Logger that is in fact getting in the way.  For best results, you should tell people how your real dæmon is actually run, in the depths of that script.  Only with that information can one construct a service unit that isn't a systemd House of Horror entry.

Comment: @JdeBP I was looking up on google about systemd House of Horror and I found your articles. I'm not so familiar with systemd yet, I hope you can give me insights. Please see my edit.

Comment: @JdeBP My initial thought of using systemd is simply to automatically starts the script in case of system reboots. After reading [this](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/wso2.html), I think it's true that the "ImportantScript" is a Poor Man's Daemon. Feels bad haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want systemd to restart your service, you want the `Restart=` service option. Your service likely exited of its own accord, as shown by `Active: active (exited)` in the systemctl output, and the fact it had a 0 exit code.

A couple of the most common possible configurationss, as documented in [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=), are:

- `Restart=always`: Unless the service was explicitly stopped (eg. `systemctl stop`, or directly calling `StopUnit` over DBus), restart it.
- `Restart=on-failure`: If the service terminated with a >0 exit code, restart it.
- `Restart=no`: The default. Don't restart the service.

These are probably the most commonly used settings -- you can find more options in the above-linked table.

Comment: My configuration always say that it is `Active: active (exited)` in most occasions. Might try this, anyway.

Comment: @annahri Then that's because `/usr/local/bin/importantScript start --instance XYZ` forks away, but you are using `Type=oneshot`, which only exists for the main process' lifetime. You want to either stop forking, or use `Type=forking`.

Comment: That's intended, because the main script executes the forever loop (something like `while watch /this/dir; do something; done &` ) and then it leaves a background process. I tried using `Type=simple`, and it ended up spawning the background processes endlessly. I don't know how to say it properly, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Well, you can't have it both ways. If you want systemd to manage your processes, you need to give it the right process to manage...

Comment: Ok, I got the point. So I have to rewrite my script. Thanks for your replies!